# new activity doesn't start when click on navigation drawer item

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

I have searched alot, tried everything what i got over stackoverflow as solution for similar kind of issue but nothing helped.
please tell me what i am making mistake in my code or is there something that i left.
Please help me.Any correction is apreciable.
Thank You

```
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
   //    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new Adapter(this, list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.nav_camera:
                //Do some thing here
                // add navigation drawer item onclick method here
                Intent i = new Intent(MyBookings.this, Categories.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_gallery:
                //Do some thing here
                // add navigation drawer item onclick method here
                break;
            case R.id.nav_slideshow:
                //Do some thing here
                // add navigation drawer item onclick method here
                break;
            case R.id.nav_share:
                //Do some thing here
                // add navigation drawer item onclick method here
                break;
            case R.id.nav_send:
                //Do some thing here
                // add navigation drawer item onclick method here
                break;
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to use fragment instead of activity in navigation drawer.

Comment: I don't need the navigation drawer in other activities. Thats why I am not using fragments.I want to start new activity when i click on items

Comment: OK. then finish current activity after start new activity.

Comment: Put log in every single case of navigation drawer click so that you can find error and also make sure that ids are proper as per your menu file, else debug your code

Comment: when i click on items in navigation drawer.....its not showing anything in log

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same issue, I fixed it by adding:

`navigationView.bringToFront();`

For your case add it after where you are initializing navigationView:

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.bringToFront();
```

Comment: This worked for me, also when the activity gets called via a containing class method.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the boolean return on your method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.nav_camera:
                //Do some thing here
                // add navigation drawer item onclick method here
                Intent i = new Intent(MyBookings.this, Categories.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_gallery:
                //Do some thing here
                // add navigation drawer item onclick method here
                break;
            case R.id.nav_slideshow:
                //Do some thing here
                // add navigation drawer item onclick method here
                break;
            case R.id.nav_share:
                //Do some thing here
                // add navigation drawer item onclick method here
                break;
            case R.id.nav_send:
                //Do some thing here
                // add navigation drawer item onclick method here
                break;
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove these two lines from end of the Switch statement

```
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
```

let me know if that helps

Answer (score 0):

change return true.and add navigation drawer line before switch statement

```
  @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle navigation view item clicks here.

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

            int id = item.getItemId();
            switch (id) {
                case R.id.nav_camera:
                    //Do some thing here
                    // add navigation drawer item onclick method here
                    Intent i = new Intent(MyBookings.this, Categories.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_gallery:
                    //Do some thing here
                    // add navigation drawer item onclick method here
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_slideshow:
                    //Do some thing here
                    // add navigation drawer item onclick method here
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_share:
                    //Do some thing here
                    // add navigation drawer item onclick method here
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_send:
                    //Do some thing here
                    // add navigation drawer item onclick method here
                    break;
            }
               return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this change::

```
Intent i = new Intent(MyBookings.this, Categories.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```